# Error-correcting capability of (7,4) Hamming code

Tags: coding-theory

I know that that a (7,4) binary Hamming code can definitely correct a single error. However, how do I prove that it definitely cannot correct 2 or more errors? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you seen proven the fact that any sequence of 7 bits is at a Hamming distance at most one from some codeword? In other words that the covering radius of the Hamming code is 1? Can you use that?

Comment: Damn it, why did you delete your other coding theory question? I was just typing an answer explaining how to extend the $(8,4,4)$ code to a $(11,4,5)$ code. Also proving that tagging three extra redundant bits is the best we can do. :-)

Comment: I am sorry! Can you post your suggestion in [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/543830/improving-error-correcting-capability-of-hamming-7-4-code) or [link](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/11365/improving-error-correcting-capability-of-hamming-7-4-code) instead? @JyrkiLahtonen

Comment: No worries! It is your call, whether you want to keep it. I was just mildly miffed by the accidental timing that I happened to be typing an answer exactly when you deleted. My answer was still in the buffer, so I only had to add a couple of sentences. It's posted in the first link now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $2^4 = 16$ codewords, and $7$ vectors that are at distance $1$ from 
each codeword. The set of $8$ vectors consisting of a codeword $\mathbf c$
plus the $7$ vectors at distance $1$ from it is called the
*Hamming sphere of radius $1$ centered at* $\mathbf c$. If the
received vector $\mathbf r$ lies in $S(\mathbf c)$, the decoder
output is $\mathbf c$, and if $\mathbf c$ is indeed the transmitted
codeword, then the decoder output is correct, that is, $0$ or
$1$ errors can be corrected by this code.

Denote this sphere
by $S(\mathbf c)$ and note that since the code can correct
single errors, $S(\mathbf c)$ and $S(\mathbf c^\prime)$ must be
*disjoint* if $\mathbf c \neq \mathbf c^\prime$.
Thus, we have accounted for $8\times 16 = 128 = 2^7$ binary vectors,
that is, these $16$ (disjoint) Hamming spheres of radius $1$ collectively
constitute the entire set of binary vectors of length $7$. Now, any
received vector $\mathbf r$ must lie in one of these spheres, and if
it is at distance $2$ or more from the *transmitted* codeword $\mathbf c$,
it is necessarily in some $S(\mathbf c^\prime)$ for 
$\mathbf c^\prime \neq \mathbf c$ and thus will be decoded into 
$\mathbf c^\prime$, that is, the decoding will be in error. In other
words, two or more errors cannot be corrected by the $(7,4)$ Hamming
code.

More generally, the $(2^n-1, 2^n-1-n)$ Hamming code has
$1 + 2^n-1 = 2^n$ vectors in each of the $2^{2^n-1-n}$
disjoint Hamming spheres of radius $1$ centered at the codewords,
and these spheres collectively constitute the entire set
of $2^{2^n-1}$ binary vectors of length $2^n-1$, and the above
argument applies to the general case as well.

Answer (score 1):

There are 4 significant bits in a message so are 16 signals without errors

In a signal there are  7 bits so there are 7 errors per signal possible
so if one error there are 7 x 16 = 104 signals with one error

There are 6x7/2  (21) ways having 2 errors in a 7 bit signal so that is 336 possible signals.

But there are only 128 different posible signals, so at least some some signals of the group with 2 errors have to be the same signal and cannot be distinghuised or decided what the message was.

simple example

1100000 is a signal with two errors

what was the message?
if error free signal was -> message was
0000000 -> 0000
1110000 -> 1000 (ok there is only one error in this one)
1100110 -> 0110
or
1101001 -> 0001