# improving error-correcting capability of Hamming (7,4) code

Tags: coding-theory

The Hamming (7,4) code can correct 1 error, and the extended Hamming (8,4) code can correct 1 error and detect 2 errors. I was wondering if we can modify the Hamming (7,4) code or extended Hamming (8,4) code, so that up to 2 errors can be corrected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get the impression that you want to have a binary 4-dimensional code with minimum distance five. [The Griesmer bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Griesmer_bound) says that the minimum length of such a code is $\ge11$, so we need to tag at least three extra redundancy bits to the $(8,4)$ extended Hamming code. It is not difficult at all to find a way that works. Consider the following generator matrix
$$
G=
\left(
\begin{array}{l}
11110000\color{red}{100}\\
11001100\color{red}{010}\\
00001111\color{red}{100}\\
10101010\color{red}{001}
\end{array}
\right).
$$
Its eight first columns form a generator matrix of the $(8,4,4)$ extended Hamming code. That code has a single weight 8 word (= the sum of the 1st and 3rd rows), and all the other non-zero words have weight four. Therefore we need to make sure that all those weight 4 words get a non-zero 3-bit tag (colored red in the above generator matrix). By looking at those red bits you see that the only non-trivial way to get all red zeros as a linear combination is to take the sum of rows one and three. But that was precisely the weight eight word of the $(8,4)$-code, so this works. It is, of course, easy to also verify this simply by listing all the 16 words of the code generated by $G$.

Comment: The distance of the 1st row and 3rd row is 4, instead of 5.

Comment: I think that the distance of the 1st row to the 3rd is 8?

Comment: But I had mangled that key sentence while recovering the answer from the buffer. Sorry about that.

Comment: so it can definitely correct all combinations of 2 errors?

Comment: Yes. If the minimum distance of a code is $d=2t+1$, it can correct all combinations of $t$ errors. Here $d=5$, so $t=2$